# Difference between load, import, textscan in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Can someone help me in understanding the main differences between load, import, textscan in MATLAB? I want to understand, when to use which one.

Answer (score 1):

There are great sources to find this out from. Type `help load`, `help import` and `help textscan` in your matlab command window. Then read. If you are really inquisitive, do the same with `doc` instead of `help`. It really helps.

OK. `load` is for loading matlab workspace data, like variables; `import` is for programming stuff you probably won't need, and `textscan` and friends are for reading variables from text files.